# RatingBar обрезается на последней пятой звезде

Tags: android, ratingbar

Не пойму, почему у меня обрезается пятая звезда рейтинга и почему такой отступ между ним и textView?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:contentDescription="@string/no"
        android:minWidth="130dp"
        android:minHeight="130dp"
        android:maxHeight="130dp"
        android:maxWidth="130dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myToolBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:text="Абракадабров Абракадабр Абракадабрович"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
    <RatingBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="0"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvAdditional"
        android:textColor="#0d580d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        tools:text="Дополнительно" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvNumberSign"
        android:text="№ "
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvAdditional"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvAdditional" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvMid"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvNumberSign"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvNumberSign"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvNumberSign" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По каким-то причинам padding все портит. Надо использовать `layout_marginLeft`

```
<RatingBar
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="0"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

Увеличенный отступ может быть следствием кривой разметки. Можно попробовать проверить на самой простой разметке, дабы понять в разметке ли дело, или в чем-то еще:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
        android:text="Абракадабров Абракадабр Абракадабрович" />

    <RatingBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="0"
        android:stepSize="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Если не поможет, то нужно проверить что у вас не переопределяется стиль `Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small`.
И как средство на крайний случай, можно сделать `android:layout_height="16dp"` для `RatingBar`. Но это как-то криво.

В любом случае я настоятельно рекомендую использовать RelativeLayout только в крайних случаях и очень внимательно следить за разметкой. В вашем случае какая-то путаница с layout_alignLeft и прочим. В данном случае можно использовать 2 вложенных LinearLayout и сильно упростить чтение разметки, а значит и количество возможных ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо! А что со второй частью вопроса?

Comment: @Новичок а вот тут нужна более полная разметка. У вас есть какой-то контейнер, в который все это сложено, но не понятно какой. И есть layout_toRightOf, который не понятно с чем выравнивает.

Comment: Обновил разметку в вопросе

Comment: @Новичок обновил ответ

Comment: @ lllyct скопировал ваш вариант разметки - не помогло

Comment: @Новичок обновил, android:layout_height="16dp" должно сработать, но все же надо проверить все остальное.